# Dependency Injection in PostSharp

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, unity-container, postsharp

I've just read the docs on PostSharp.net about [Importing Dependencies from the Target Object](http://doc.postsharp.net/##importing-dependencies) and need some clarification from WCF service perspective.

This is my trimmed cache aspect in which I'm trying to use *ICache* via Unity:

```
[Serializable]
public class CacheAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect, IInstanceScopedAspect
{
    [IntroduceMember(Visibility = Visibility.Family, OverrideAction = MemberOverrideAction.Ignore)]
    [CopyCustomAttributes(typeof(ImportAttribute))]
    [Import(typeof(ICache))]
    public ICache Cache { get; set; }

    [ImportMember("Cache", IsRequired = true)] 
    public Property<ICache> CacheProperty;

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var cache = this.CacheProperty.Get();            
    }        

    object IInstanceScopedAspect.CreateInstance(AdviceArgs adviceArgs)
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    void IInstanceScopedAspect.RuntimeInitializeInstance()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.LoadConfiguration();

        var distributedCache = container.Resolve<DistributedCache>();
        this.CacheProperty.Set(distributedCache);
    }
}
```

My issue is with the **RuntimeInitializeInstance** method.

I'd like to know if setting the CacheProperty in this method is the correct approach or should I be doing it differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing the `ICache` dependency in the [`[RuntimeInitializeInstance]`](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/M_PostSharp_Aspects_IInstanceScopedAspect_RuntimeInitializeInstance) method is one of the correct approaches, but the provided implementation is not efficient, because you create and configure a new container instance every time.

Usually, it's more convenient to let the DI container to resolve the dependencies for you instead of setting them manually.

The [`[IntroduceMember]`](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/T_PostSharp_Aspects_Advices_IntroduceMemberAttribute) attribute tells PostSharp to add the `Cache` property directly to your service class. When resolving the service instance during run-time, Unity container can set this `Cache` property for you automatically.

You can tell Unity to set the property value by annotating it with the `[Dependency]` attribute ([Annotating Objects for Property (Setter) Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507426%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx)). For this attribute to be copied to your service class you also need to apply the [`[CopyCustomAttributes]`](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/T_PostSharp_Aspects_Advices_CopyCustomAttributesAttribute) attribute.

```
[IntroduceMember(Visibility = Visibility.Family, OverrideAction = MemberOverrideAction.Ignore)]
[CopyCustomAttributes(typeof(DependencyAttribute))]
[Dependency]
public ICache Cache { get; set; }
```

The attributes in your example were copied from the documentation and demonstrate the same principle for the MEF container.